# Python 3: How to log warnings and errors to log file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Say I have a `While` loop that runs forever(it does system monitoring).

It has three conditions,

```
While True:

    if something1
        Everything is OK!
    if something2
        Warning
    if something3
        Error
```

The first, I don't want anything for. The second, I'd like to add a warning to a logfile. For the third, the same - except it's an error.

Since these are in a while loop, can I still just add a logger to something2 and something3? Do I start out with the below?

`import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()`

But how do I add warning and error to each respective if statement so it writes to the same logfile?

Comment: Maybe this helps you [Follow me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try doing it like this

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Comment: The information of warning or error (file, line, and error / warning itself) are not printed. It is important to use in these cases : logging.captureWarnings(True)   ... to capture the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Use [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#module-logging) module:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log', level=logging.DEBUG, 
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
...    

try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    logger.error(err)
...
```

Also you can write `logging.warning` and `logging.info`, as @crai noted.