# create multiple log files python

Tags: python, logging

I want to save my results as a log file, so I am thinking to import logging module. I understand that to output a file, the code is very straightforward.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='logger.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.debug('debug message')
logging.info('info message')
logging.warn('warn message')
logging.error('error message')
logging.critical('critical message')
```

However, what if I want to output multiple log files? for example, in the following for loop, each iteration will output a log file, how should I do this?

```
for i in range(1,10):
  print (i)
  #output a log file to save I value
```

I tried to use these code, but it's not working.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    filename = str.format('mylog%d.txt' % i)
    logging.basicConfig(format=log_fmt, level=logging.DEBUG, filename=filename)

    logging.debug('This is debug message')
    logging.info('This is info message')
    logging.warning('This is warning message')
```

Comment: Refer this [Logging to two files with different settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `format` function of strings incorrectly. You're trying to use string interpolation, which is an entirely different method of formatting strings. You should try something like this:

```
filename = 'mylog{0}.txt'.format(i)
```

The `{0}` explicitly states that you should take the first value passed to `format`. You could leave it as `{}` if you'd like - it makes no real difference.

Comment: thx, but still, it only create one log file, and all the results are showing in this single file.

Answer (score 1):

1. About file name:

   ```
   filename = str.format('mylog%d.txt' % i)
   ```

   is equal to:

   ```
   filename = 'mylog%d.txt' % i
   ```
2. For output to multiple files you can use multiple handlers.

   **Logging** class that handle logging.

   ```
   root_logger = logging.getLogger()
   ```

   Return you root handler. You can add or remove handlers to logger.

   ```
   root_logger.handlers
   ```

   Contains list of handlers of root logger.

   ```
   first = root_logger.handlers[0]
   first.close()
   root_logger.removeHandler(first)
   ```

   remove first handler.

   ```
   new_handler = logging.FileHandler(file_name)
   formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s ' + ' %(message)s', '%H:%M:%S')
   new_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
   root_logger.addHandler(new_handler)
   ```

   Add new formatter to root_handler.
   You can output log to any files at the same time.

For more info read:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html