# Logging to separate files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm using python's logging module. I've initialized  it as:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in every of my modules. Then, in the main file:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,filename="log.txt")
```

Now, in the app I'm also using WSGIServer from gevent. The initializer takes a log argument where I can add a logger instance. Since this is an HTTP Server it's very verbose.

I would like to log all of my app's regular logs to "log.txt" and WSGIServer's logs to "http-log.txt".

I tried this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,filename="log.txt")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

httpLogger = logging.getLogger("HTTP")
httpLogger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("http-log.txt"))
httpLogger.addFilter(logging.Filter("HTTP"))

http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', int(config['ApiPort'])), app, log=httpLogger)
```

This logs all HTTP messages into http-log.txt, but also to the main logger.

How can I send all but HTTP messages to the default logger (log.txt), and HTTP messages only to http-log.txt?

EDIT: Since people are quickly jumping to point that this [Logging to two files with different settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings) has an answer, plese read the linked answer and you'll see they don't use `basicConfig` but rather initialize each logger separately. This is not how I'm using the logging module.

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings)

Comment: None of those use basicConfig or module-level logging. Please don't be so dupe-happy and take time to read the questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not sure about the duplicate. The question and answers there do not deal with two loggers along the same branch of the logging tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to disable [propagation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate):

```
httpLogger.propagate = False
```

Then, it will no longer propagate messages to its ancestors' handlers which includes the root logger for which you have set up the general log file.