# Logger module in python does not create multiple files

Tags: python, class, logging

I am creating a logger with unique name as per object unique label during creating of a object. I want different log files for different objects. It is creating only single file and appending all logs to it

I have created 5 instance of class student with incremented label from 1 - 6
in constructor(**init**), I create a logger object with unique name by appending the label to it. After run only one file is created instead of 5 individual files which was expected

```
#python2.7
import logging
class student:
    def __init__(self,label):
        self.label = label
        file_name ="Log_Rollno" + str(self.label)
        logging.basicConfig(filename=file_name,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='w')
        print "CREATED " + file_name
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logger.info("Message from Object" + str(self.label))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1,6):
        student_obj = student(i)
```

I expect : Individual files as per objects unique label (Log_Rollno1, Log_Rollno2)

Actual Result: Messages from all created objects get appended to only one file

(File Name : Log_Rollno1)
2019-07-16 12:52:49,884 Message from Object1
2019-07-16 12:52:49,890 Message from Object2
2019-07-16 12:52:49,894 Message from Object3
2019-07-16 12:52:49,898 Message from Object4
2019-07-16 12:52:49,904 Message from Object5

Comment: I think this is because you are setting the base logging to the filename

logging.basicConfig(filename=file_name,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='w')

surely this should be in the config of each of the loggers that you spawn.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `logging.basicConfig()` only once. It configures the `root` logger and if there is a handler attached already it will return silently without doing anything.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) states:

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.

In your case the first instance will configure the logger. Instances created later will not.

You might want to configure the logger manually by attaching a `Handler` to it instead of using `logging.basicConfig()`.

[Example in the docs showing how to attach a handler.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging)