# Write different type of info to 2 different log files on Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have usage and application logs.
I want to write application logs to `app.log` file and usage logs to `usage.log` file.

Here is how I have tried to do this:

```
# Application Log:
logging.basicConfig(filename = "app.log", level = logging.DEBUG, format = "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
# Usage Log:
logging.basicConfig(filename = "usage.log", level = logging.DEBUG, format = "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
```

For some reason I don't see the second file created.

Please advise what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my issue:

```
import logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')


def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):
    """To setup as many loggers as you want"""

    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)        
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger

# first file logger
logger = setup_logger('first_logger', 'first_logfile.log')
logger.info('This is just info message')

# second file logger
super_logger = setup_logger('second_logger', 'second_logfile.log')
super_logger.error('This is an error message')

def another_method():
   # using logger defined above also works here
   logger.info('Inside method')
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings)

Answer (score 0):

add different Handlers to the default logger:

```
import logging

def init_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('info.log')
    error_handler = logging.FileHandler('error.log')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    error_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    logger.addHandler(error_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# use
init_logging()
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.info('abc')
```