# How to write different level logs into seperate files in python logging module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

How to write seperate log files for different log levels in python flask application using the logging module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings#11233293 This should have your question covered.

Comment: will it be possible to do with same object, but just by passing different level of logs the files to write on gets seperated?

Comment: def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO): you can set the third parameter level to other logging levels.