# Python Modular Logging to different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to setup an environment where I can log to multiple files without adding too much complexity. The current setup is outlined below. What's convenient about this is that I can just call `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` anywhere after initiating `set_logger()` and it just works "globally" without any extra code.

Now let's say I would like to have a separate file that only logs security related messages, without adding too much extra complexity? E.g. something like `logger2 = logging.getLogger(__name__, file='security.log')` that is callable from within the module would be ideal. Is that somehow possible? All Stack Overflow answers I found basically suggested having to construct a new logger in each module instead.

```
# settings.py
LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
LOG_FORMAT = '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s():%(lineno)d] – %(message)s'
LOG_FILE = 'orchestrator.log'
LOG_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logs', LOG_FILE)
LOG_BACKUPS = 21

def set_logger(debug: bool = None):
    _LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG if debug else LOG_LEVEL
    logging.basicConfig(
        format=LOG_FORMAT,
        datefmt='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',
        level=_LOG_LEVEL,
        handlers=[
            logging.StreamHandler(),
            logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
                LOG_PATH,
                encoding='utf-8',
                when="d",
                interval=1,
                backupCount=LOG_BACKUPS
            )
        ]
    )
```

```
#main.py
import settings
settings.set_logger()
```

```
#module.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings

Comment: Yes; but then `logger = setup_logger('first_logger', 'first_logfile.log')` has to be called from every module that wants to use said logger, right? Which results in `settings.py` having to be imported everywhere.

Comment: `setup_logger` should be called once for all modules

Comment: How do I use e.g. `super_logger` in a second module then after initiating it in `main.py`?