# Python log to different destinations conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I'm logging to a file and sysout using `logging` in Python 3.8

Currently, the logs go to both the file and sysout. But I want to log to either of them conditionally.

My current code is:

```
logpath = constants.LOGS_LOCATION

fileHandler = RotatingFileHandler(logpath, maxBytes = 500000, backupCount = 10)
localLogFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s")
fileHandler.setFormatter(localLogFormatter)

stdoutHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = MyJsonFormatter()
stdoutHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

logging.root.handlers = []
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    handlers=[
        fileHandler,
        stdoutHandler
    ]
)
```

So when I do:

```
logging.info("goes to both file and sysout")
```

The above goes to both file and sysout, but I want the log to either go to file or sysout depending on my business requirement.

How can I achieve this? Can it be done parameterized or different loggers?

Comment: What is the difference between the messages?

Comment: how is the logger meant to know which handler would process the message? normally loggers give a copy of th emessage to all handlers, why not just make two separate loggers and call them as needed.

Comment: @PeterWood I think I framed the question confusingly. I've updated the question

Comment: What is the condition you depend on?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle How can we make two separate loggers? I'm using the inbuilt `logging` in python

Comment: @PeterWood the condition is on the business logic. Say I want business critical logs to go to file whereas not so important logs to sysout

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232230/logging-to-two-files-with-different-settings

Comment: @PeterWood Thank, but I'm facing issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64643466/python-file-logger-also-logging-to-stdout

Comment: this is a good resource too https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations