# Python File logger also logging to stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

In python 3.8, I've configured logger as:

```
logging.root.handlers = []

fileHandler = RotatingFileHandler(logpath, maxBytes = 500000, backupCount = 10)
localLogFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s")
fileHandler.setFormatter(localLogFormatter)

file_logger = logging.getLogger('file_logger')
file_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
constants.file_logger = file_logger

constants.file_logger.info("Fetching access token")
```

The above logs to a file, but also prints following to stdout:

> INFO:file_logger:Fetching access token

I don't wish the log to be printed to stdout. How can I avoid this and make the log printed only to the file?

Comment: The problem is not within the code shown here. Are there any logging calls happening before that? What is the `constants` thing referenced? As shown here the code does not write to stdout, so there must be some more logging configuration going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the basicConfig parameter and pass only the Filehandler in it. Don't pass the `StreamHandler()`

```
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler(<path to file>)
], format='%(asctime)s %(env)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
```

Comment: basicConfig is effectively a no-op when a handler already exists, which from the problem description is likely the case.